# jupyter notebook Server error: error

Tags: windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

This question has already been asked, but it wasn't answered.

So basically I am using anaconda prompt to launch the jupyter notebook on Windows 10.
It works but I can't navigate for long in the jupyter "explorer" because very quickly it can't find directories and it shows: `server error: error`.

I don't know if it is related but I can't neither open a jupyter notebook from anaconda even if it is installed.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the `server error: error` problem since I restarted my computer.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue. It started working okay again after I'd switched off Ghostery (it's an ad-blocker) in my Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It got fixed after I stopped my Chrome Ad Blocker extensions on the jupyter page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is AdBlock. Pause on this web

Comment: I have AdBlock installed and I am not pausing it on jupyter notebook and I never had this problem. I do not think this is an answer to the problem.

Comment: Yes, correct. My issue is that I copied and pasted my Jupiter notebook website from Microsoft edge to Chrome, then server error happened, once paused AdBlock on THIS website, Problem solved.